# Is there a client-side version of onPlayerJoin?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Title says it all, I just wanna detect when a player joins a server client-side, and also how would I send a message to the client, not through the server? (the mod is supposed to send a message when the player joins and play a sound when you are not moving on a server like hypixel where it wont have the mod) *weird mod, I know* (Also this is done in 1.8, if that matters much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices, both with some downsides:

1. `ClientConnectedToServerEvent`, although it fires on a different thread than usual, and may fire slightly earlier than you want
2. `EntityJoinWorldEvent`, although it fires in a lot of other cases too, so you'd have to do some additional checks to make sure it's actually the player joining that triggered it

Comment: hmmmmm, okay so I will try "EntityJoinWorldEvent" how would I filter it so it only triggers when its the player joining it?

Comment: Not sure, but can you know where the player comes from before joining the world? If from Nether you know that is not on joining the game. I'm not familiar with forge. So maybe I'm in the wrong track. 